# 60s sci-fi novel about New Mexico A&M

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

About 1963, I read a book that could have been one of Heinlein or Asimov’s Juvies.
It had a reference to the Co-op Engineering program at what had been New Mexico A & M (Now New Mexico State), with the protagonist doing some work at White Sands.
It pretty much set me on the career path that I have enjoyed, and I would like to find it again. Any ideas?

Comment: This was a sci-fi novel, correct?

Comment: Perhaps [The Man Who Sold the Moon?](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=ip90CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT185&dq=white+sands+heinlein&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=white%20sands%20heinlein&f=false)

Comment: This is very sparse. Other than working as a scientist, what were they doing? Was there a plotline? What was the main character's name? Were there any events you remember? Was there a love-interest? What makes you think it's a YA book? Can you recall any dialogue? What made it memorable?

Comment: See below-It looks like we have an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably *[Rocket Man](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/lee-correy/rocket-man/)* by Lee Correy - pen-name of G. Harry Stine, who worked at White Sands in the early '50s. Juvenile from 1955, the main character is a young man who comes to White Sands to help build the first Mars rocket. The book is dedicated to 'The Co-Op Students of the New Mexico College of Agriculture and Mechanical Arts and White Sands Proving Ground'.

> A colorful space story of fifty years hence has some logical suppositions even if its doings are not altogether convincing. As it is told in the first person, we are on the inside from the moment when nineteen year old Tim Layard sets foot in the international engineering school in New Mexico to his landing on Mars a year later. Determined to be a rocket man and hoping to get chosen for the Space Force, which is based nearby, both Tim and his roommate are soon given their chances. They are screened, found exceptional and, with the Sherpa boys named Tenzing and Posang, are recruited for Earth's second trial expedition to Mars. Suspense builds to a rousing climax. On Mars they discover the failure of the first expedition, get acquainted with some rather cuddly Martians, etc...

Comment: That sounds correct-I do remember the dedication, which set me on the path--I went to NMSU, as a Co-op, first tracking satellites for the Navy GPS, then at NASA FRC (Dryden).
All because of 1 book. Been a long ride, and a good one. 
Unfortunately, its a totally out-of-print unavailable book. I'd like to get a copy, so if anyone has a source for it, let me know. Thanks a bundle!

Comment: There are copies on ebay right now for $29.99, $174 & $300. 'Starship Through Space' is a sequel, even though it was published first.